# Composite Foreign Key Constraint via PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin, rdbms, composite-key

Is there a way to add a composite (multi-column) foreign key to an InnoDB table via the PhpMyAdmin interface?  I already have the appropriate composite primary key in the target table, and I can single column foreign key constraints, but I can't find a way in the interface to do the composite one.

```
Table Log
- Date
- Service
PRIMARY KEY (Date,Service)

Table Issue
- Issue_Id
- Log_Date
- Log_Service
PRIMARY KEY Issue_Id
FOREIGN KEY (Log_Date=Log.Date,Log_Service=Log.Service)
```

Everything is already set up except the foreign key; I go into the PhpMyAdmin relation view and I can only see how to set up a FK against Log.Date and not against Log.Service at all.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I can only figure out how to set up simple FK constraints in phpMA.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similiar problem setting up a composite foreign key in phpMyAdmin and maybe my solution could help you as well.

Here's my setup:

[image: My setup]

As you can see I have a composite primary key in my ConferenceRoom table, part of which is also a foreign key to `streetaddress` in table Office (this might differ from your problem).

This composite primary key is to be referenced by a composite foreign key in table InstPicture but the problem for me was that, in spite of having defined both as primary key indexes, phpMyAdmin would only reference the `name` column in the ConferenceRoom primary key, and not the `office_streetaddress` column.

What I was missing here was that I had not set up the relation between ConferenceRoom and Office *before* trying to set up the one between ConferenceRoom and InstPicture. I guess I forgot to handle the strong enities first, as database methodology dictates.

When the relation had been defined between ConferenceRoom and Office, the `office_streetaddress` column showed up in the list of indexed columns and could the be referenced by the `conferenceroom_office_streetaddress` column in table InstPicture.

I hope this could help you as well, maybe try creating a separate index for your Log.Service column. Or if that is a FK, set up its relations and then try again.