# phpmyadmin many to many relationship composite key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a junction table between two tables in phpmyadmin. This is the first time I've used phpmyadmin and struggling a bit.

My session table has a composite key made up of 4 columns from that table. The junction table has the foreign keys (and their indexes). I would like to know if it is possible to have a composite primary key as a foreign key in the junction table.

If I change the session table to have only one column in the primary key, the junction table accepts, but this is not what i am needing. I am worried that phpmyadmin doesn't accept composite primary keys as a foreign key in the many-to-many junction table. Please see images below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpA42.png]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Composite Foreign Key Constraint via PhpMyAdmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020423/composite-foreign-key-constraint-via-phpmyadmin)

Comment: I think I figured this one out - I needed to create the composite key as a "unique" key first and then link to the junction table which has my foreign keys. Then I went back and made the combination of keys as a composite key. Seems to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately after spending long hours on this issue, it turns out that when you use phpmyadmin, you can't have a composite key from one table referencing a composite key from another table.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this wil help you:

```
create table t1
(
    nom varchar(32), 
    nom_2 varchar(32),
    nom_3 varchar(32),

    CONSTRAINT pk_attr PRIMARY KEY (nom, nom_table, nom_owner),
);

create table t2
(
    nom_t1 varchar(32),
    nom_2 varchar(32),
    nom_3 varchar(32),


    CONSTRAINT fk_t1 FOREIGN KEY (nom_t1, nom_2, nom_3) REFERENCES t1(nom, nom_2, nom_3)
);
```